# Angularjs How to edit a copy of a variable object in $scope from touching the original?

Tags: angularjs

I just realised that whatever changes I make with variable `$scope.ratings` affect also `$scope.data` I don't want that.

```
  $scope.data = [        {  
          "0":"1",
          "1":"Creativity",
          "2":"5",
          "3":"1",
          "4":"2017-01-17 21:24:42",
          "5":"ratings",
          "6":null,
          "ID":"1",
          "Title":"Creativity",
          "Value":"5",
          "Parent":"18",
          "Timestamp":"2017-01-17 21:24:42",
          "Category":"ratings",
          "Author":18
       }
    ]
        var myid = 18;
    var newdata = [];
        for( var i in $scope.data ){
          if($scope.data[i].Author == myid) {
              //alert($scope.data[i].ID);
          newdata.push($scope.data[i]);
         }

        $scope.ratings_temp= newdata;
        $scope.ratings = newdata;

    }
        $scope.ratings[0].ID = 'loool';
      console.log($scope.ratings);
      console.log($scope.data);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`angular.copy` is used to clone an object in AngularJS. So your code may be like:

```
newdata.push(angular.copy($scope.data[i]));
```